# Can you create more than one element of a list at a time with a list comprehension in haskell?

Tags: haskell, list, list-comprehension

So, for example, say I had a list of numbers and I wanted to create a list that contained each number multiplied by 2 and 3. Is there any way to do something like the following, but get back a single list of numbers instead of a list of lists of numbers?

```
mult_nums = [ [(n*2),(n*3)] | n <- [1..5]] 
-- this returns [[2,3],[4,6],[6,9],[8,12],[10,15]]
-- but we want [2,3,4,6,6,9,8,12,10,15]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use concat.

```
concat [ [(n*2),(n*3)] | n <- [1..5]] 
output: [2,3,4,6,6,9,8,12,10,15]
```

Answer (score 17):

I find that extending the list comprehension makes this easier to read:

```
[ m | n <- [1..5], m <- [2*n,3*n] ]
```

It might be helpful to examine exactly what this does, and how it relates to other solutions. Let's define it as a function:

```
mult lst = [ m | n <- lst, m <- [2*n,3*n] ]
```

After a fashion, this [desugars](http://haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) to

```
mult' lst = 
    concatMap (\n -> concatMap (\m -> [m]) [2*n,3*n]) lst
```

The expression `concatMap (\m -> [m])` is wrapping `m` up in a list in order to immediately flatten it—it is equivalent to `map id`.

Compare this to @FunctorSalad's answer:

```
mult1 lst = concatMap (\n -> [n*2,n*3]) lst
```

We've optimized away `concatMap (\m -> [m])`.

Now @vili's answer:

```
mult2 lst = concat [ [(n*2),(n*3)] | n <- lst]
```

This desugars to:

```
mult2' lst = concat (concatMap (\n -> [[2*n,3*n]]) lst)
```

As in the first solution above, we are unnecessarily creating a list of lists that we have to `concat` away.

I don't think there is a solution that uses list comprehensions, but desugars to `mult1`. My intuition is that Haskell compilers are generally clever enough that this wouldn't matter (or, alternatively, that unnecessary `concat`s are cheap due to lazy evaluation (whereas they're lethal in eager languages)).

Answer (score 5):

In some similar cases concatMap can also be convenient, though here it doesn't change much:

```
concatMap (\n -> [n*2,n*3]) [1..5]
```

Comment: For `instance Monad []`, `(>>=) == flip concatMap`... it seems that Chris's answer glossed over that part, but this answer is a subset of the one above.